# what is the differences between extend and expand in a DBMS?

Tags: rdbms, database

I searched for extend and expand the database and find both of them are same .
what is the differences between extend and expand in a DBMS or RDBMS ?

Can we say "extend" is physical and "expand" in virtual growth ?

Comment: I am not familiar with a specific technical usage for these terms in the world of relational databases.  Either could refer to the growth of the underlying data files that store the data.  Can you provide some context for your question?

Comment: yes , these are related to increase a database's size but have differences , what are that differences ?

Comment: . . In any given database, these terms are going to have meanings specific to that implementation.  I don't think there is a "generic" meaning for these across all databases, the way there is between, say, an `inner join` and a `left outer join`.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.extol.com/blog/?p=171

> In the “extended” option, it would stand to reason that if the notes
>   applied to header that the file would be extended in length. If the
>   company anticipated getting five separate notes that could each be 120
>   characters in length, the header file would see five new fields added
>   – each being 120 positions. Problem: What if six or more notes were
>   received? There would be no room at the inn and any number of notes
>   beyond five would be lost. What if zero notes were received? Then five
>   fields of 120 characters (600 positions) would sit empty – a very
>   “inefficient” database design.
>
> In the “expanded” option, neither the header nor the detail file is
>   extended but instead the database is expanded by adding a new file
>   specific to “notes.” Each note will create a new record in the notes
>   file. If five notes are received, five records will be added. If 100
>   are received, 100 will be added. If zero are received then the file
>   will be empty – a very “efficient” database design.

Comment: it is especially for EXtol , isnt it ?

Comment: It is, and I probably should not reply to queries on a Saturday night... am adding another answer below...

Answer (score 0):

extend increases the available space for a database: [from IBM](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tsminfo/v6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.itsm.srv.ref.doc/r_cmd_dbspace_extend.html), where 
expand increases the amount of available space which the database is using: [from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176037%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

My take on it is that if you have 1TB of space on a disk, you database can extend up to the available disk space, minus whatever is already on the disk - if you have an unlimited growth potential... but if you expand your database to include another disk, then you can extend your database up to a size which encompasses the available space on both disks (with unlimited growth potential)

Again, Saturday night... so take what you read with a grain of salt!